# What are the difference for Target Selection Options for clang toolchain?

Tags: clang, cpu-architecture, clang++

I'm stuck on understanding the clang --target, -mcpu, -march flags

Can someone give a clear explanation on what is the difference between them?

Originally I thought need to specify -mcpu (which I assume means CPU) and -march but then I can't figure out how --target fits into the picture. Sometimes it tells me that -march or -mcpu options is not used and in that case if  only --target are use what are the default values for other arguments and what it occurs if i don't specify them ?
it's mentioned on clang's user manual
`For example, if your target is arm-none-eabi, the default CPU will be arm7tdmi using soft float, which is extremely slow on modern cores, whereas if your triple is armv7a-none-eabi, it’ll be Cortex-A8 with NEON, but still using soft-float, which is much better, but still not great.` but they are not mentioning how to set a default mcpu from --target argument...

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: *they are not mentioning how to set a default mcpu from --target argument.* - Because `-target` can't do that.  You use `clang -target arm-linux-eabi  -mhard-float -mcpu=cortex-a53   -O2 -S hello.c` or whatever to make a `.s` you can look at.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for answering, yes but am asking what's the default value of mcpu in case we don't set it. It's mentioned that it will get the value all (-mcpu=all) but there is no explanation of what this all mean